# Error in paytab payment method in android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I am android developer,I add the payment method **paytab** **gateway** in android app to make a online payment.But after receive card detail it's move on error page that just like below.

[Paytab error message screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c6nT.jpg)

So anyone know about this error and when this error generated.

Comment: Contact your payment provider.

Comment: Where we can get Android SDK zip.?

Comment: Make sure you're using the correct SecretKey and MerchantI_d (Email address of the Merchant in your Android app).